# Bootstrap icon attaching itself to the ending of each div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very interesting and strange problem.

I have entered an icon within my button like this

```
 <div class="span10 details">
   <h4 style="margin-bottom: 0;" class="pull-left">Book Details</h4>
   <button class="pull-right toggleBtn span1"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
   <p class="clearfix"></p>
   <hr>

   <div class="bookDetails">
     <p>Here</p>
   </div><!--.bookDetails-->
</div><!--.span10-->
```

and the icon seems to be attaching itself to the ending of each div. I have no loops going on, disabled all js (except boostrap). I have no idea what is going on here. I'll attach an image of what is happening below.

[image: weird icon multiplication]

Answer (score 3):

It seems you forget to close off your `<i>` tags. Try this.

```
<button class="pull-right toggleBtn span1"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
```